# SQL where two fields are similar using "GROUP BY"

Tags: sql, group-by

I have a database of names, some of the names haven't been insert in the correct fashion. SecondName has sometimes been entered as FirstName.

```
+-----------------+--------------+
|    FirstName    |  SecondName  |
+-----------------+--------------+
| Bob             | Smith        |
| Gary            | Rose         |
| John            | Jones        |
| Smith           | Bob          |
| Gary            | Oberstein    |
| Adam            | Sorbet       |
| Jones           | John         |
+-----------------+--------------+
```

I've tried different grouping queries

```
select `FirstName`
     , `SecondName`
  from `names`
 where ( `FirstName` 
       , `SecondName` ) 
    in ( select `FirstName`
              , `SecondName`
           from `names`
         group
             by `FirstName`
              , `SecondName`
         having count(*) > 1 
       )
```

But I can't get anything to produce

```
+-----------------+--------------+---------+
|    FirstName    |  SecondName  |  Count  |
+-----------------+--------------+---------+
| Bob             | Smith        | 2       |
| John            | Jones        | 2       |
+-----------------+--------------+---------+
```

Comment: so you want to group by first name, last name and last name, first name?

Comment: I want to count the number of times FirstName and SecondName are the same.

Comment: that does not make sense, you have Bob Smith as 2 in your example.

Comment: Yes, that's the expected output.

Comment: Then you need to normalize as my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a trick to do this, you need to normalize your names, a quick way to do this is if you alphabetize first name and last name then group on the result.

```
SELECT name_normalized, count(*) as c
FROM (
  SELECT CASE WHEN FIRSTNAME < LASTNAME THEN FIRSTNAME||LASTNAME
              ELSE LASTNAME|| FIRSTNAME END as name_normalized
  FROM names
) X
GROUP BY name_normalized
```

Notes:

- This is the simple case, you could add the normalized result as a column if you want to see the original values.
- You may need other normalization -- it depends on what your rules are.  For example UPPER() to ignore case and TRIM() to remove whitespace.
- You can add or ignore other columns as is required for matching normalization -- Birthday, Middle Initial etc.
- Oten time a hash on the normalized string is faster to work with than the string -- your data model might require one or the other.

Answer (score 2):

If the `COUNT()` itself isn't important, you can easily separate duplicates with an `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT n.FirstName, n.SecondName, n2.FirstName, n2.SecondName
FROM Names n
INNER JOIN Names n2 on n.FirstName = n2.SecondName and n.SecondName = n2.FirstName
```